# How to override supportedInterfaceOrientations in Flutter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter

I am trying to prevent some of my UIViewController to auto rotate when the iPhone is rotated physically. I know how to do it in iOS native way by overriding these methods `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate`. But how do I override theses methods in Flutter? Or Is there any other way to do it in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations inside the main() method:
   SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp);

 
Additionally, add entries UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait to your plist